# Can a Powershell loop be written to check for an existing file and rename a new file if one is found?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a couple of powershell scripts to convert an email in Outlook to a text file for eventual submission to a ticketing system via API. The focus of my question is on the first part which takes the text of the email from Outlook and saves it to a text file with the email subject as the filename. So far, this is the code I have:

```
$olFolderInbox = 6
Add-Type -assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook'
$GetOutlook = New-Object -ComObject 'Outlook.Application'
$olName = $GetOutlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$olxEmailFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)

$SubFolders = $olxEmailFolder.Folders | Where-Object -FilterScript {
  $_.Name -match 'Tasks' 
}
$TargetFolder = $olxEmailFolder.Folders.Item('Completed')

$SubFolders.Items |    
ForEach-Object -Process { $filename = $psitem.Subject
  $filename1 = $filename.ToString() -replace '\W','-'
  $psitem.Body | Set-Content "C:\Test\$filename1.txt"
  $psitem.Move($TargetFolder)
}
```

This works well enough for emails with a unique subject line and it moves them to a separate Email folder so it doesn't process them again the next time it runs. However, if a new email comes in with an identical subject to one the script already processed, the old txt file that was exported will get overwritten with the new one since the subjects match and, consequently, it would be given the same file name.

I wanted to see if there is a way to craft a loop that, before it outputs to a file, it checks if the file already exists and, if it does, to append a number to the end of the file name (1,2,3,etc) and repeat the check to see if that file exists, increasing the number to append again and again until it gets a filename that doesn't already exist.

Something that has a logic like this if it were trying to export to a file named subject.txt:
check if subject.txt already exists
subject.txt already exists, rename file to output to subject1.txt
check if subject1.txt already exists.
subject1.txt already exists, rename file to output to subject2.txt
check if subject2.txt already exists.
it does not already exist, so output to subject2.txt

I'm new to powershell so I'm still learning how loops work and if the commands even exist to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to avoid `while ($true)` loops like the other answer - here's a recursive function instead. This also ensures the input is a valid path.

```
Function Get-NextFilename 
{
    Param 
    (
        [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$Path, 
        [Parameter ()]
        [Int]$Suffix = 0
    ) 
    $testPath = $Path.FullName
    if ($Suffix -gt 0)
    {
        $testPath = Join-Path -Path $Path.Directory -ChildPath "$($Path.BaseName)$($Suffix)$($Path.Extension)"
    }
    if (Test-Path -Path $testPath)
    {
        Get-NextFilename -Path $Path -Suffix ($Suffix + 1)        
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Output -InputObject $testPath
    }
}
```

You simply pass your desired full path name:

```
Get-NextFilename -Path "C:\Test\$($filename1).txt"
```

You can add a sanity check at the start of the function (after the parameters) to avoid infinite loops:

```
if ($Suffix -eq 10)
{
    Write-Error -Message "Too many tries" -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

Ideally I would make the function so you provide a path (`C:\Test`) and desired filename (`$($filename1).txt`) and build the target full path in the function - let me know if you want that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function you can add to your script to look for an unused filename:

```
Function Get-Unused-Filename {
    param ([string]$PathAndFileBase, [string]$Extension)

    $num = 0
    $possiblepath = $PathAndFileBase + $Extension
    while ($True)
    {
        if (-Not (Test-Path $possiblepath)) {
            return $possiblepath
        }
        $num = $num + 1
        $possiblepath = $PathAndFileBase + $num.ToString() + $Extension
    }
}
```

It takes the beginning of a pathname, like "C:\Test\MyMail", and an extension, like ".txt".

It then uses Test-Path to see whether just that full path -- "C:\Test\MyMail.txt" -- exists. If not, it returns it.

If there *is* a file named "C:\Test\MyMail.txt", then it starts trying C:\Test\MyMail1.txt, C:\Test\MyMail2.txt, and so on, until it finds an unused filename or you turn off the power.

So where you're now calling:

```
$psitem.Body | Set-Content "C:\Test\$filename1.txt"
```

You would instead do something like:

```
$newfilename = Get-Unused-Filename -PathAndFileBase "C:\Test\$filename1" -Extension '.txt'
$psitem.Body | Set-Content $newfilename
```